# anchor tag is not working in toggle div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Why is the anchor tag not working? I have a two divs. when I click on the first div the second div is displayed but in the first div anchor tag is not working.

```
<script>
$('.description').hide();
$('.more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.flight-row').find(".description").toggle();
});
</script>
<div id="trips">
    <div class="flight-row">
        <div class="flight-row-main more">
            <div><img src="view/images/user.png" alt="user.png" title="1 traveler" height="15" width="15"></div>
            <div class="button"><a href="index.php?act=travelerUserDetail&amp;flightTrainNumber=G8 208&amp;date=2017-01-30" class="btn btn-warning">Choose</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="description-upper-div">
                <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>LKO<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>DEL</span>
                <span>2017-01-30</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put your code in a document.ready event handler: `$(function() { /* your JS code here */ });`

Comment: script is working but only anchor tag is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It isworking just fine. It is Recommended that scripts should be at the bottom of the page.

```js
$('.description').hide();
$('.more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.flight-row').find(".description").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trips">
    <div class="flight-row">
        <div class="flight-row-main more">
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200.jpg" alt="user.png" title="1 traveler" height="15" width="15"></div>
            <div class="button"><a href="index.php?act=travelerUserDetail&amp;flightTrainNumber=G8 208&amp;date=2017-01-30" class="btn btn-warning">Choose</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="description-upper-div">
                <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>LKO<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>DEL</span>
                <span>2017-01-30 </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually anchor tag action is different. On the click of anchor tag description div should not be display. Did you get my point?

Comment: You can toggle it the opposite way,